# Sound is muting and jumping to max

Tags: sound

My sound is jumping from what ever volume is set to 0 and back up.

I've tried disabling auto mute in alsamixer but it doesn't help in any way. I've also saved the setting but it does not even work after I've set it so..

Any idea what it can be?

I've already had this bug under fedora, ubuntu and currently kubuntu 15.04

Comment: Do a trouble shoot for sound problem https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: It's not one of the common "I have no sound" problems. We have sound, but the volume jumps erratically from 100% to 40% and then somewhere in between. Very annoying. Nothing in dmesg. Irregular intervals. No other apps running except a music player (tried with various).